# Get outputs values from the linked arm template

Tags: azure, azure-arm-template

hoping someone can help pinpoint what's missing in my approach.

I'm using visual studio 2017 if this makes any difference.

I've two arm templates; maintemplate and the linkedtemplate.

In the maintemplate I'm trying to reference a linked template and retrieve an output value from it in my maintemplate's outputs section so that the outputs contains values from both the templates.

Here is the **linkedtempalte** outputs section;

```
"outputs": {
    "LoadBalancer-pip1": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',variables('publicIPAddressName1'))).IpAddress]"
    },
    "LoadBalancer-pip1-DNS-Name": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',variables('publicIPAddressName1'))).dnsSettings.fqdn]"
    }
  }
```

Here is the **maintemplate** outputs section;

```
"outputs": {
    "jump Box VM Public IP address": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',variables('hub-cc-jbox-pipName'))).IpAddress]"
    },
    "Load Balancer VIP1": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference('hub-plb').outputs.LoadBalancer-pip1.value]"
    },
    "Load Balancer VIP1 DNS Name": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference('hub-plb').outputs.LoadBalancer-pip1-DNS-Name.value]"
    }
}
```

Accordingly to this link; https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-linked-templates#link-or-nest-a-template

it should be possible as long as it's not a nested template, which it's not.

Here is my maintemplate section where I'm making the link to the linkedtempalte;

```
{
        "name": "hub-plb",
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
        "dependsOn": [],
        "properties": {
          "mode": "Incremental",
          "templateLink": {
            "uri": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', variables('hub-plbTemplateFolder'), '/', variables('hub-plbTemplateFileName'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
            "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
          },
          "parametersLink": {
            "uri": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', variables('hub-plbTemplateFolder'), '/', variables('hub-plbTemplateParametersFileName'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
            "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
          }
        }
      }
```

**When I try to validate / deploy the template it fails with this message;**

```
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Creating Deployment" on target "xyz-rg".
08:23:09 - New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 8:23:08 AM - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation 
08:23:09 - failed: 'The template output 'Load Balancer VIP1' at line '1034' and column '31' is not valid: The language expression 
08:23:09 - 'reference('hub-plb').outputs.LoadBalancer-pip1.value' is not valid: the string character 'p' at position '42' is not 
08:23:09 - expected..
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: can you try this: `"[reference('hub-plb').outputs['LoadBalancer-pip1-DNS-Name']value]"` or try changing output name so it doesnt have a `-` in it. I'd also suggest renaming every output to a string without `-` or ` `

Comment: any luck yet? can you give feedback?

Comment: @4c74356b41 thanks for the hint. The validation passed after I removed the "-" from the output names. The syntax I had is right so all I did to make the validation passed is to change the name and removed any "-" or space from it. e.g. "LoadBalancerVIP1": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference('hub-plb').outputs.LoadBalancerpip1.value]"
    },

Comment: I also posted a note on the MSFT article link for them to consider adding a note to avoid this validation failure.

Comment: ok, consider accepting this answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the problem was with the output name, after removing the `-` from it, everything started to work.